# Make relationship with two code paths using GIT

Tags: git

I did a project on code path A.
Then got a copy of A and make it B and did some changes on it.
Then A,B got changes on those. Is there a way for me to add these to a git repo now and have the relationship. Eg make B a branch of A ?

Code path A is a folder named A. 
This not started on GIT. Here copied means just took a copy of the folder. Not a git branch. Now I want to move this to git with a relationship. (eg: B is a branch of A)

Comment: What is a "code path"? What do you mean by "got a copy of A and make it B"?  Do you mean you made a branch at A and called it B?

Comment: @Schwern Edited the question with answers to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following steps:

1. Create a new git repository using `git init`.
2. Copy the entire contents of A into your working folder.
3. Edit your `.gitignore` so that you don't commit irrelevant files.
4. Commit the changes using `git add` and `git commit`. Now you have
   the master branch pointing to `A`.
5. Create and checkout a new branch "B" on that commit, using `git checkout -b`.
6. Copy the entire contents of `B` to your working folder, overwriting `A`.
7. Commit everything using `git add` and `git commit`.

In the end you'll have the master branch with `A`'s content, and the branch `B` with `B`'s content.

Comment: this seems to be the answer. Say both A and B will develop in to two separate products, you think still this method is most suitable ?

Comment: In this case, you probably want A and B to be in two different repositories, but share a common dependency C, that is maintained in a third git repository. This enables to supports a different life cycle for each product, especially when each product is maintained by a different team.